# extending existing database - interfaces

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on extending the existing project which has been in production for couple of years and I need to extend a few **existing** entities, lets call them a,b,c,d.

When I now think about the designing of a database all the a,b,c,d should have some sort of inheritance, but changing the schema too much is impossible at this point.

Now all the a,b,c,d have their own primary keys but they all have to implement certain interfaces like - "bookmarkable", "taggable", "viewable" etc.

Would it make sense to keep creating tables like 
a_saved, b_saved, c_saved, d_saved or a_tags, b_tags, c_tags etc to model the relation? But then again.. I would have to create THE SAME code to handle each of the scenarios where the only difference it's the table name!

I think better solution would be to create an new table - lets call it "object" and try to model some inheritance - for each entity create an entry in the "object" table and store that id in it's table and then create one relational table to map object_tag relation.

Does this sound like feasible solution or possibly error-prone and will bite me in the feature?

Comment: Look into views: You can I think represent what you want with views and use these for your new operations

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to your second idea would be to create a single table that maps an extension by a combined (entity type, entity ID) key. See here for a sample schema and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c0235/1/0